# How to install ruby on rails on elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation

Is their any one who can help me to install ROR on elementary OS? 
I am new on elementary OS. I want to install ruby on rails on my elementary OS.
can anyone please tell me how can i install ruby on rails on elementary OS.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried my answer (and remember to mark it as answer)

Comment: The answer below is a good one. As a general rule, being based on Ubuntu 16.04, if you need something for elementary 0.4 just google the question and replace elementary for ubuntu and most times you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands to install Ruby on rails

```
sudo apt install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash

rbenv install 2.3.0
rbenv global 2.3.0
ruby -v
gem install bundler
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
rbenv rehash
```

Source : https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

Comment: Can you please tell me why the following errors occurs?

smehsan@smehsan:~$ exec $SHELL
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: syntax error near unexpected token `PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: `esacexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'
smehsan@smehsan:~$

Comment: @smehsan What error?

Comment: @smehsan Just restart the terminal instead

Comment: smehsan@smehsan:~$ exec $SHELL bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: syntax error near unexpected token PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: esacexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' smehsan@smehsan:~$

Comment: @smehsan Run `scratch-text-editor ~/.bashrc` and remove the last line and replace it with `export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH`

Comment: can you please tell which line of code should i replace?
here is a screen shot from the text-editor.
http://imgur.com/9BrPJg2

Comment: @smehsan Link is broken

Comment: sorry,
here is the correct link 
http://imgur.com/9BrPJg2

Comment: Line number 168

Comment: opening new terminal shows the following errors.

bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: syntax error near unexpected token `PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH'
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: `export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH'

Comment: @smehsan Remove only line 168.

Comment: Now it shows this error.
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 169: syntax error near unexpected token `"$(rbenv init -)"'
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 169: `eval "$(rbenv init -)"'

Comment: Then also remove line 169

Comment: what's wrong,
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 169: syntax error near unexpected token `"$(rbenv init -)"'
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 169: `eval "$(rbenv init -)"'
smehsan@smehsan:~$

Comment: @smehsan Then remove it again

Comment: Oh Man,
This is horrible. 
I just update elementary os and when i restart it ask for password and when i enter my password nothing happen. 
i have check different solution for this but nothing works.

Comment: @smehsan That is probably something else and not relating to the `.bashrc` edit.Try asking another question

Comment: Thank You.
When i will get the latest problem solution, i will again contact with you to perfectly install ROR.
Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Suici Doga,
Can you please tell me why i am seeing all of those errors until now?
I hope you will help me.

Comment: @smehsan What error

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40231/discussion-on-answer-by-suici-doga-how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-elementary-os).

Comment: can you please tell me why this error come `BUILD FAILED (elementary OS 0.3.2 using ruby-build 20160426-25-gabb7d1d)`

Answer (score 0):

What Nguyen said worked for me.

Use a text editor and go to the root directory. (I'm using Sublime Text 3)

If you don't have one, you can use the following commands:

```
cd /
nano .bashrc
```

Scroll down to the end of the document, then create the line break (Enter in Windows/Linux)

It should look like this:

```
esac
# rbenv
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

If you're using the 'nano' command, press Ctrl+O then Enter to save the document.

Press Ctrl+X to exit nano.

Thank you, Nguyen.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

For someone who have problem with rbenv and bashrs, this code is worked for me. (We need 'enter' between esac and export)